What is the cumulative kernel distribution using an Epanechnikov kernel?
good morning everyone.
I understand that kernel density estimation is a non-parametric technique used to estimate the probability density function of a random variable from a sample of data, with the kernel density defined as follows:
$$
\hat{f}(x) = \frac{1}{n h} \sum_{i=1}^{n} K\left(\frac{x - X_i}{h}\right)
$$
where:

$\hat{f}(x)$ is the density estimate at point $x$,
$n$ is the number of observations,
$h$ is the bandwidth
${K}(u)$ is the kernel function.

I assume that to obtain the cumulative distribution function, one must integrate $\hat{f}(x)$
$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \hat{f}(t) \, dt
$$
The thing is, I have read that the Epanechnikov kernel is the most efficient, which is defined as follows:
$$
K(u) = \frac{3}{4}(1 - u^2) \quad \text{if } \vert u \vert \leq 1
$$
$$
K(u) = 0 \quad \text{if } \vert u \vert > 1,
$$
I would like to know how to calculate $F(x)$ using this type of kernel.
Thank you very much, and best regards.

What exactly are you looking for? Have you tried just doing the integration?

Hi @LSK21 my question is precisely about how to integrate the Epanechnikov Kernel, what is the analytical expression of the kernel? I have some doubts about the absolute values

The estimate of the cdf is given by
\begin{align}
\hat{F}(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n K \left( \frac{t-X_i}{h} \right) dt \\
&= \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^x K \left( \frac{t-X_i}{h} \right) dt \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x-X_i}{h}} K(u)du \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n I_K \left( \frac{x-X_i}{h} \right),
\end{align}
where $I_K(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x K(u) du$. Now, note that since the support of $K$ is $[-1, 1]$, we have that $I_K(x) = 0$ for $x < -1$ and $I_K(x) =1$ for $x > 1$ (since in this case we are just integrating over the entire support). The case that remains is for $x \in [-1, 1]$. This is then just a simple integration, giving us
\begin{align}
I_K(x) &= \int_{-1}^x \frac{3}{4}(1-u^2)du \\
&= \left[ \frac{3}{4} u - \frac{1}{4} u^3 \right]_{u=-1}^{u=x} = -\frac{1}{4} x^3 + \frac{3}{4} x + \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
The only thing that remains is to plug this in for our estimator $\hat{F}$ above.

Thank you very much  @LSK21

No problem. Since you accepted my answer as satisfactory, would you mind upvoting it as well?
